# Check db insert result by pandas to_sql command - Flask

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have this function:

```
def getHistoricRates():
    """ Here we have the function that will retrieve the historical rates from fixer.io, since 1999 """
    rates = []
    response = urlopen('my_key')
    data = response.read()
    rdata = json.loads(data.decode(), parse_float=float) 
    rates_from_rdata = rdata.get('rates', {})
    for rate_symbol in ['USD', 'GBP', 'HKD', 'AUD', 'JPY', 'SEK', 'NOK']:
        try:
            rates.append(rates_from_rdata[rate_symbol])
            with open('usio.json', 'w') as outfile:
                json.dump(rdata, outfile)
            history_currency = json.load(open('usio.json'))
            df = pd.read_json(open('usio.json'))
            df
            conn = sqlite3.connect('usio.db')
            df.to_sql('usio', conn, if_exists='replace')
        except KeyError:
            logging.warning('rate for {} not found in rdata'.format(rate_symbol)) 
            pass

    return rates
```

This is my schema file:

```
drop table if exists rates;
create table rates (
  id integer primary key autoincrement,
  currency text,
  rate real
);
```

This code, reads a json file called `usio.json` then, by using the `to_sql` pandas function, it stores it into a SQLite db called `usio.sql`, however, it seems to work pretty fine, but my doubt or issue is, where can I check the result?

I mean I don't see any file created, is it maybe because I haven't initialized the SQLite database into my Flask application?

Or maybe I forgot to specify something else?

Comment: Have you tried `db = sqlite3.connect('usio.db')` and `db.execute('select * from rates')`?

Comment: Not the execute command, but my point is, should there be some new file as a result?

Comment: I don't think so. You are writing to that database specifically. You can copy that db to something local and do testing there, if that is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a separate method that does the database checking for you.

```
    def printNewTable():
        db = dqsqlite3.connect('usio.db')
        for row in db.execute('select * from rates'):
            print row
    printNewTable()
```

Comment: Thanks, well, I just want to check the result, can't check it anywere, even after this, maybe I do need to print that to some resulting file? Anyways, gonna work on it, and ask a new question if needed, thank you again.

Comment: @NeoVe The table does not have anything in it yet. Maybe see if the table is created first with `SELECT name FROM my_db.sqlite_master WHERE type='table';`